# Use if statement within .str.find()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, if-statement

I would like to know If I have an if statement that looks something like this:

```
if int(i) > 10:
    return 0
else:
    return -1
```

where `i` is equivalent to a row entry in `df["price"]` (df is a pandas dataframe) defined as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["price", "Number"], data=[["10", "07367"], ["20", "08356"], ["9", "07745"]])
```

how can I use `df["price"].str.find(...)` together with the above if statement to filter the data by the true condition?

I would like output that looks like the following:

```
0  -1
1   0
2  -1
```

I have been struggling with how to implement it, please assist.

Comment: Can you add some data sample,[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Apologies, I have added some sample data.

Comment: What is the expected output? Why do you want to use `str.find`?

Comment: I think you can use `np.where(df.price.astype(int) > 10, 0, -1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally its easiest to first convert to optimal `dtypes`. That way all operations will be quicker - of course, it depends on your application whether this matters. But if things are numbers, let them be numbers (explicit > implicit).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["price", "Number"], data=[["10", "07367"], ["20", "08356"], ["9", "07745"]])
df['price'] = df.price.astype(int)  # or float 
df['number'] = df.number.astype(int)
```

You can then add your criteria as a colum (or just use the output). Apply or map are not so quick, so its better to use the `np.where` suggested by others or any other comparison that will use numpy under the hood. For example:

```
df['criteria'] = -1 * (df.price <= 10).astype(int)  # quicker to not use map or apply
df.criteria
```

Comment: Nice Solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [gt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) + [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.3/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["price", "Number"], data=[["10", "07367"], ["20", "08356"], ["9", "07745"]])
result = df.price.astype(int).gt(10).map({False: -1, True: 0})
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
0   -1
1    0
2   -1
Name: price, dtype: int64
```

Or if you prefer, you could use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), as mentioned by @coldspeed in the comments.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["price", "Number"], data=[["10", "07367"], ["20", "08356"], ["9", "07745"]])
result = np.where(df.price.astype(int) > 10, 0, -1)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[-1  0 -1]
```

Answer (score 1):

simply you can use lambda functions

```
df.price.apply(lambda x : 0 if int(x)>10 else -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['price'] =df['price'].astype(int)
df['output'] = np.where(df['price']>10, 0, -1)
df

   price    Number  output
0   10     07367     -1
1   20     08356     0
2   9      07745    -1
```

The syntax is: `np.where(condition, valueIfTrue, valueIfFalse)`